# In devextreme popup assignedto data is not coming

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have implemented the dx-popup which is opening and showing data very well but Assigned to data is not showing properly.

On Trainings.Component.html Side code written as

```
 <div *ngFor="let trngs of trainings">
   <dx-button text="View" (onClick)="onShowTrainingDetailInfo(trngs.trainingdetail)">
   </dx-button>
 </div>


 <dx-popup  [showTitle]="true" title="Orientation Training Plan" [closeOnOutsideClick]="true" [(visible)]="trainingDetailVisible">
 <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
  <div *ngFor="let trainingdetail of currentTrainings">
   {{trainingdetail.task}}// Here the data is showing
     <span *ngFor="let assigned of trainingdetail.assignedto1">
       {{assigned.trainingAssignedName}}<br />//Here The data is not showing
    </span>
     <dx-button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle condition_popup" text="View" (onClick)="onShowTrainingPopupInfo(trainingdetail.trainingPopup)">            
    </dx-button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </dx-popup>

 <dx-popup [showTitle]="true" title="Company Manual Training" [dragEnabled]="false" [closeOnOutsideClick]="true" [(visible)]="trainingPopupVisible">  
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
     {{currentTrainingPopup.task}}
</div>
```

TrainingsService.ts is as below(Please excuse if some data is missed)

```
 const training: Trainings[] = [
{
trainingsId: 1, plan: 'Orientation', dateAssigned: '11/2/18', status: 'In progress', done: 40 
, trainingdetail:
  [
    {
      trainingDetailId: 1, trainingsId: 1, done: 'true', status: 'In progress', task: `Read the attached list of common terms and abbreviation used in your
       job. Ensure you learn them up and understand them.`, dueDate: 'Sept 16', attachment: '',
      assignedTo1:
        [
          { trainingsAssignedId: 1, trainingAssignedName: 'john', trainingAssignedImage: 'user-photo.png', trainingDetailId: 1 }
        ],
      trainingPopup:
      {
        trainingDetailId: 1, done: 'true', task: `Read the attached list of common terms and abbreviation used in your job. Ensure you learn
             them up and understand them.`, dueDate: 'Sept 16', attachment: '', attachmentFile:
          [{ attachmentFileId: 1, fileName: 'Terms & Abbreviations.docx' }, { attachmentFileId: 1, fileName: 'Terms & Abbreviations1.docx' }],
        history: [
          { historyDetailId: 1, title: 'Ingrid Desna Assigned Task to John Smith and Angela Muller', date: '09/09/16' },
          { historyDetailId: 2, title: 'Ingrid Desna Created Plan', date: '09/09/16' }
        ],
        assignedTo2: [
          { trainingsAssignedId: 1, trainingAssignedName: 'john', trainingAssignedImage: 'user-photo.png', trainingDetailId: 1 },
          { trainingsAssignedId: 2, trainingAssignedName: 'john 2', trainingAssignedImage: 'user-photo-2.png', trainingDetailId: 1 }
        ]
      }

    }
   ]
  }
]; 

 @Injectable()
 export class TrainingsService {
   getTraining(): Trainings[] {
     return training;
   }
 }
 export interface Trainings {
   trainingsId: number;
   plan: string;
   dateAssigned: string;
   status: string;
   done: number;      
   trainingdetail: TrainingDetails[];
 }

 export interface TrainingDetails {
   trainingDetailId: number;
   trainingsId: number;
   done: string;
   task: string;
   status: string;
   dueDate: string;
   attachment: string;
   assignedTo1: TrainingDetailsAssigned[];
   trainingPopup: TrainingDetailsPopUp;
 }

 export interface TrainingDetailsAssigned {
   trainingsAssignedId: number;
   trainingAssignedName: string;
   trainingAssignedImage: string;
   trainingDetailId: number;
 }
```

Trainings.component.ts file below code

```
export class TrainingsComponent implements OnInit {
  currentTrainingPopup: TrainingDetailsPopUp[];
  currentTrainings: Trainings[];
  trainings: Trainings[]; 
  public trainingDetailVisible = false;
  public trainingPopupVisible = false;

  constructor(service: TrainingsService) {
    this.trainings = service.getTraining();
  }
  onShowTrainingDetailInfo(trainingDetail) {
    this.currentTrainings = trainingDetail;
    this.trainingDetailVisible = true;
  }  
 onShowTrainingPopupInfo(trainingPopup) {
  this.currentTrainingPopup = trainingPopup;
  this.trainingPopupVisible = true;
 }   
}
```

The only issue is that where I placed assignedto1 in Popup the data is coming as empty instead of showing john data else all the data is coming well.
I don't know what mistake I have done over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bad spelling...

you have in model "assignedTo1" (ts file)

and in your html file you have "assignedto1"

P.S. Sometimes you can easily find some bug when you build as "production" (via @ngtools/webpack) because it verify integrity of html / ts files

Comment: hey that working can you help me out for trainingPopup data

Comment: Could you explain what happened?
because I can't find any error in that code :/
(It's easier when I know popup behaviours)

Btw... use json pipe to show information about object
it will be easier to you to find some bugs :)
e.g. (in html file):
           {{currentTrainingPopup | json}}